# Data not being POSTed through AJAX request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I have this AJAX request:

```
$("#searchagain_form").submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/searchforward",
      data: {engine: $("#engine_options").find(".on_engine").text()}
    });
});
```

This is my form:

```
    <%= form_for :searchagain, :url => {:controller => 'results', :action => 'searchforward'}, :html => { :id => "searchagain_form" } do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :search, :value => @search, :id => 'searchagain_bar' %>
      <%= f.submit :value => "search!", :id => 'searchagain_submit'  %>
    <% end %>
```

However, checking my logs, the data does not seem to be POSTed to the server when the form is submitted. Any idea why?

Comment: you should serialize your form data (and thus include the token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not cancel the submission, so the page will unload instead of sending the ajax-request.
Append a `return false;` to the function.

But however, it's not clear what kind of element `#engine_options .on_engine` is, if it is an text-input use `val()` instead of `text()` (text() should return nothing for text-inputs).

When it is a textarea it will return the textNode inside the element, not any later modified text. So use val() also for textarea.

Comment: yeah you're right with the first thing you said. I actually wanted to send some data in addition to the data I was submitting in the form, so I realized the right thing for me to do was to pass it in a hidden field. `#engine_options .on_engine` is actually a link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a semicolon here:

```
{engine: $("#engine_options").find(".on_engine").text();}
```

Other than that, you can use a traffic monitor like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to monitor the post and make sure it's sending what you want it to.

**Edit:**

```
$('#searchagain_form').serialize()
```

will also give you an object with all your form data

Comment: so? is the data being sent properly?

Comment: the data is not being sent. I see no sign of the data in my params hash

Comment: did you use a web traffic monitor like charles?

Comment: how difficult is it to set up. I don't feel like installing something new :/

Comment: its easy and it will make your life easier.

Comment: ehh you know what, I could just use a hidden field instead of ajax. don;t know why im putting myself through all this trouble

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add an error handler in your ajax params?

```
$("#searchagain_form").submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/searchforward",
      data: {engine: $("#engine_options").find(".on_engine").text()},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });
});
```